# How to enclose texts and equations in the following types of boxes?

Tags: boxes

How to enclose texts and equations in the following types of boxes (for outputs see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22395/170039)),

```
$$ \bbox[yellow]
{
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (1)
}
$$
```

and,

```
$$ \bbox[border:2px solid red]
{
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (2) 
}
$$
```

I have tried to use them directly in my LaTeX document but they didn't work. it seems that one needs to use some extra packages to make them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no pre-existing `\bbox` macro, but it can be defined to specifically work in math mode (shown here for the unframed version).

The underlying macros from the `xcolor` package are `\colorbox{color}{content}` and `\fcolorbox{frame color}{color}{content}`.  In both cases, the lengths `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` control the edge-space buffer and border thickness, respectively.

One would need to add `\displaystyle` to the box content in order to achieve non-compressed fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\bbox[2][white]{\colorbox{#1}{$#2$}}
\begin{document}
\[ \bbox[yellow]
{
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (1)
}
\]
\[ \fboxrule=2pt\fcolorbox{red}{white}
{$
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (2) 
$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

The OP wishes to learn a bit more about the influence of `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.  These are the standard LaTeX dimensions that control just about all box constructions.  One must be careful in that redefining them will carry throughout your document unless their redefinitions are "group limited".  So, defining them in the preamble will affect the whole document.  However, since LaTeX math environments form their own group, one can freely change them between `\[...\]` and not have them reach outside the particular equation.

`\fboxsep` controls the space around the box content (for example the amount of yellow that extends to the left of `e^x` and to the right of `(1)`, and above and below, as well.  The length `\fboxrule` specifies the frame thickness.

Below, I take the above example, and respecify these two parameters so that one can see the effect.  I have also placed the first equation in `\displaystyle`.  In the first equation, the `\fboxsep` is set to 1pt, which is less than the default (3pt, if I recall).  In the 2nd example, `\fboxsep` is set to 10pt, which increases the white space around the equation, and the frame thickness is increased to 5pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\bbox[2][white]{\colorbox{#1}{$#2$}}
\begin{document}
\[ \fboxsep=1pt\relax\bbox[yellow]
{\displaystyle
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (1)
}
\]
\[ \fboxsep=10pt\relax\fboxrule=5pt\relax\fcolorbox{red}{white}
{$
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
\qquad (2) 
$}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the second style?

Comment: @user170039 see update.

Comment: Can you please include in the post how in both cases, the lengths `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` control the edge-space buffer and border thickness, respectively? I am really novice in this respect.

Comment: @user170039 Please see addendum.